# Converting R code into bytecode

Tags: r, compilation, package

I am trying to make a package in R, which is solely a R code, without the use of any external language.
Now, I read that converting the package into the byte code would give me significant speed improvements, this can be done during the package installation by specifying
`<R CMD INSTALL --byte-code>`

I was wondering if there is an option through i which I could pre compile the R codes into bytecode and do a `R CMD INSTALL` of the compiled bytecode package instead of asking the user to write `<R CMD INSTALL --byte-code>`

Is there a way to get the package to be build in bytecode only?

Answer (score 6):

Yes. In your DESCRIPTION file, specify:

```
ByteCompile: yes
```

Then your package will be automatically byte compiled by default if the capability exists.

Comment: This would only compile in byte code if I specify R CMD INSTALL --byte-code.If I am wrong let me know.
I want an option in which the user installs like a normal package, the only way I see it possible is if my R files are no longer R scripts but a file containing byte code.Is it possible.

Comment: Ok .. thanks !! One more question I wanted to ask How would I know if the ByteCompile capability exists?

Comment: It exists in all versions of R from 2.14 onwards.

Comment: I tried what you said , it was getting installed earlier but after setting ByteCompile to TRUE. I get the following error : 
`/usr/lib/R/bin/INSTALL: line 34:  9964 Done                    echo 'tools:::.install_packages()'
      9965 Segmentation fault      | R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES= LC_COLLATE=C "${R_HOME}/bin/R" $myArgs --slave --args ${args}`

Comment: Odd. Try doing 'true' in lower caps? Otherwise, I don't know. I think it might be time to contact the R-dev or R-help mailing list since you may have found a bug.

Comment: ok .. the problem still persists.
I will ask around for help with the R-dev people